# deploy the database of an asp.net mvc application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I was a php/mysql developper, now i'am with asp.net mvc and sql server. I used to importe the database to a script file and export the file to the server which I don't like. now i am working on a website in asp.net mvc. I will tell you how I imagin things and tell me if there is anything wrong :

- Create the database model using sql server management studio.
- importe the database file using visual studio and entity framework to create mapping classes.
- upload all files to the server including the database file which is a local file on my project folder.

will this steps work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question is too vague. Try to be specific, including code and details where possible.

Overall, yes, you're on the right track. You're describing a database-first approach where you create the database first and then use Entity Framework to generate the code.

My only piece of advice is that you should try to have the database as abstract - don't force your application to only accept a database that is stored locally, and don't let your application only accept a SQL database, etc. It will make it easier to transfer from a local/development database to an enterprise-level.